# How to access the jQuery event object in a Seaside callback

Tags: jquery, ajax, events, smalltalk, seaside

Basically, I want to translate the following into Seaside Smalltalk:

```
$(".myDiv").bind('click', function(e) {
    console.log(e);
});
```

Besides that I don't want to `console.log` the event, but access it in my ajax callback.

The most promising approach seemed to be something like

```
html div
    onClick: (html jQuery ajax callback: [:v | self halt] value: (???);
    with: 'Foo'.
```

But I couldn't find any way to access the event that caused the callback. Intuitively, I would try

```
html jQuery this event
```

for the `???` part, but the Seaside jQuery wrapper doesn't know any message that comes close to `event`.

Any help is appreciated. There has to be away to access the event data...

Comment: Wow. Congratulations to the one who downvoted this well received question after a year without even bothering to comment. Grow up!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To serialize the x mouse coordinate of the event use the following code:

```
html div
    onClick: (html jQuery ajax
        callback: [ :x | x inspect ]
        value: JQEvent new pageX);
    with: 'Click'.
```

There are other properties in the event object that you might be interested in, just serialize them with the same AJAX request by adding multiple `callback:value:` constructs in a cascade.

In the very latest JQuery code you can use `html jQuery event` to create the event object. This was missing up to now.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. JQEvent seems to be missing. My jQuery Core version is jf.87 - is this a version problem or what could I be doing wrong?

Comment: I am at lr.106. You can try to load the latest code, but no guarantee that it works. It looks like there is a new Seaside release to be expected soon.

Comment: I tried to, but it doesn't work (at least not when I only update jQuery Core and its direct dependencies). Can you say anything how soon this will be? We are on a tight schedule, unfortunately...

Comment: I suggest that you load all the latest packages into a fresh image with the following Gofer scripts: http://github.com/renggli/builder/blob/master/scripts/seaside3.st and http://github.com/renggli/builder/blob/master/scripts/seaside3-komanche.st. Or you grab a nightly build from the website http://www.seaside.st/download/pharo.