# Getting the value of the Javascript receiver in a Seaside JQuery callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback, seaside

My question is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2984682/how-to-access-the-jquery-event-object-in-a-seaside-callback) - how do get what would be javascript *this* (so that I can get its value assuming its a form text input) ? I am trying to send the value of a text input to the callback you see:

```
html textInput id: #thingy; 
 onClick: (html jQuery ajax 
  callback:[:x | x inspect]
  value:(html jQuery event currentTarget ????));
   with: 'I am the value the poster wants to see inspected in the above callback block!'.
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to fire the callback when you click simply bind serializeThisWithHidden on the onClick event.

```
html textInput id: #thingy; 
 onClick: (html jQuery ajax serializeThisWithHidden);
  callback:[:x | x inspect];
  with: 'I am the value the poster wants to see inspected in the above callback block!'.
```

Out of my head  :)

Answer (score 1):

To get the value in the ajax callback you would use

```
html textInput id: #thingy; 
        onClick: (html jQuery ajax 
        callback:[:x | x inspect] value: html jQuery new value);
        with: 'I am the value the poster wants to see inspected in the above callback block!'.
```